# Is it possible to import all views in folder in ExtJS MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs, view

Assume we have such ExtJS app folder structure:

```
/app
  /view
    /windows
      /window1.js
      /window2.js
      /window3.js
```

Is it possible to import all views in `view.windows` folder from Controller like:

```
views:[
  'windows/*'
]
```

instead of

```
views:[
  'windows/window1.js',
  'windows/window2.js',
  'windows/window3.js'
]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is possible:

```
requires: ['AppName.view.windows.*']
```